# python parsing a string

Tags: python, string

I have a list with strings.

```
list_of_strings
```

They look like that:

```
'/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/exp-*/exp-*/otherfolder/file'
```

I want to part this string into:
    `/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/exp-*` and put this into a new list.

I thought to do something like that, but I am lacking the right snippet to do what I want:

```
list_of_stringparts = []

for string in sorted(list_of_strings):
    part= string.split('/')[7]  # or whatever returns the first part of my string
    list_of_stringparts.append(part)
```

has anyone an idea? Do I need a regex?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using array subscription which extracts one (eigth) element. To get first seven elements, you need a [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) `[N:M:S]` like this:

```
>>> l = '/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/exp-*/exp-*/otherfolder/file'
>>> l.split('/')[:7]
['', 'folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3', 'folder4', 'folder5', 'exp-*']
```

In our case `N` is ommitted (by default 0) and `S` is step which is by default set to 1, so you'll get elements 0-7 from the result of `split`.

To construct your string back, use `join()`:

```
>>> '/'.join(s)
'/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/exp-*'
```

Comment: Perfect that is exactely what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this,

```
>>> s = '/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/exp-*/exp-*/otherfolder/file'
>>> s.split('/')[:7]
['', 'folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3', 'folder4', 'folder5', 'exp-*']
>>> '/'.join(s.split('/')[:7])
'/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/exp-*'
```

Using `re.match`

```
>>> s = '/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/exp-*/exp-*/otherfolder/file'
>>> re.match(r'.*?\*', s).group()
'/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/exp-*'
```

Comment: s.split('asterisick')[0]+'*'

Comment: Avinash, Is there anything that _you_ can't do with a regex? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example suggests that you want to partition the strings at the first `*` character. This can be done with [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.partition#str.partition):

```
list_of_stringparts = []

list_of_strings = ['/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/exp-*/exp-*/otherfolder/file', '/folder1/exp-*/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/exp-*/exp-*/otherfolder/file', '/folder/blah/pow']
for s in sorted(list_of_strings):
    head, sep, tail = s.partition('*')
    list_of_stringparts.append(head + sep)

>>> list_of_stringparts
['/folder/blah/pow', '/folder1/exp-*', '/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/exp-*']
```

Or this equivalent list comprehension:

```
list_of_stringparts = [''.join(s.partition('*')[:2]) for s in sorted(list_of_strings)]
```

This will retain any string that does not contain a `*` - not sure from your question if that is desired.